# Почему по-прежнему могу подключиться с помощью psql без указания пароля, хотя в pg_hba.conf для host all all all указано reject?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, аутентификация

Всем привет. Запускаю докер контейнер, изменив метод аутентификации на reject:
[image: docker-compose.yml]

[image: secect * from pg_autid;]

Почему значения полей rolcanlogin и rolpassword для роли app не изменились и по-прежнему могу подключиться с помощью psql без указания пароля, хотя в pg_hba.conf для host all all all указано reject?

[image: pg_hba.conf]

Answer (score 0):

Обрабатывается первая запись, подходящая по адресу, базе данных и типу соединения и  то, что мы в конце конфига добавили reject отбрасывается в этом случае.